# Java + Python на сервере

Tags: java, python

У меня есть серверное приложение на Java. Возникла необходимость запускать пользовательские скрипты, для этого я решил использовать Python, так же нужно ограничит некоторые возможности Python (типа доступа к файлам) тк это сервер.

Как организовать (библиотеки, рекомендации, статьи) совместную работу Java и Python (Из Java запускать код на Python, передавать скрипту и получать то него какие-то данные)?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Смысл от питона, если на явке можно все сделать?

Comment: @And пользовательские скрипты (пион не обязательно можно любой простой и удобный скриптовый язык)

Comment: Зачем городить, когда `Java` справится без проблем и на сервере и на клиенте.

Comment: @And Да я тоже люблю Java, но Java не такой компактный как Python и JS, а так же он не интерпритируемый

Comment: Да, да, да, подключать 100 библиотек, писать клиент на `JS` или `Python`, а после чтобы скачали и тоже еще 100 либ подключили? Смешно. А явка на любом компе уже есть и на любой ос. И ничего больше качать и подключать не требуется, все из коробки запускается. Ну это так на вскидку, а вообще, решайте сами, хотите велик, пишите, велик =))

Comment: @And скрипты на 1-10 строк в браузере прекрасно пишутся

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Java есть движок для JavaScript - Nashorn. Запускаемые на нём скрипты легко ограничить в возможностях с помощью [ClassFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/nashorn/jdk/nashorn/api/scripting/ClassFilter.html). Впрочем, политика безопасности по умолчанию там достаточно строгая, может подойти и без дополнительных манипуляций.